# SQL update statement - trying to update whole table error

Tags: java, sql, derby

I'm using a Derby db and I'm trying to update every single column in one of my tables.

I'm using the following statement:

```
String stmt = "UPDATE APP.DATAVAULT SET DID = ?, DTITLE = ?, DUNAME = ?, DPASS = ?, DSANSWER = ?, DPIN = ?, DURL = ?, DNOTES = ?, PID = ? WHERE DID = ?, DTITLE = ?, DUNAME = ?, DPASS = ?, DSANSWER = ?, DPIN = ?, DURL = ?, DNOTES = ?, PID = ?";
```

I've done an update before, using the following statement:

```
String stmt = "UPDATE APP.PERSON SET PSNAME = ? WHERE PID = ?";
```

Is there an easier way to update an entire table? If not, what am I doing wrong with this statement, as I keep receiving the following error:

```
Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 1, column 137.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
WHERE DID = ?, DTITLE = ?, DUNAME = ?, DPASS = ?, DSANSWER = ?, DPIN = ?, DURL = ?, DNOTES = ?, PID = ?
```

should be this

```
WHERE DID = ? AND DTITLE = ? AND DUNAME = ? AND DPASS = ? AND DSANSWER = ? AND DPIN = ? AND DURL = ? AND DNOTES = ? AND PID = ?
```

So replace `,` with `AND`.

Answer (score 4):

More than one clause should be added with `AND` not with comma(,). It must be `WHERE DID = ? AND DTITLE = ? AND...`

Answer (score 2):

The commas in your WHERE clause should be ANDs

`String stmt = "UPDATE APP.DATAVAULT SET DID = ?, DTITLE = ?, DUNAME = ?, DPASS = ?, DSANSWER = ?, DPIN = ?, DURL = ?, DNOTES = ?, PID = ? WHERE DID = ? AND DTITLE = ? AND DUNAME = ? AND DPASS = ? AND DSANSWER = ? AND DPIN = ? AND DURL = ? AND DNOTES = ? AND PID = ?";`